# Does challenge progress persist between characters in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does challenge progress carry over -- not just the stat boosts rewarded by them -- between characters on one account? For example, if I'm working to kill 1,000 bandits, can I achieve that with 500 on one character and 500 on another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, each character has to complete the challenge themselves.

This is a good thing, however -- because you get an additional badass rank for each completion. Meaning more Badass Tokens.

Comment: For some of the more annoying or time-consuming challenges this can be a pain, but there are plenty you will achieve just by playing through the game naturally (# kills, finding guns of X rarity, amassing fortune, etc)

Comment: Plus, it's not actually possible to *fail* one as there aren't any time limits.